# Difficulty with making new Nodes

Tags: c++, function, nodes

I am making a Huffman program and I am on the decoding part. I currently working on a function that creates a tree based on the input string and it creates a tree of h nodes and returns a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Hnode{
 string data;
 int count;
 Hnode *left, *right;
 Hnode(string data) : data(data), count(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 Hnode() : data(""), count(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 Hnode(Hnode *left, Hnode *right) : data(""), count(0), left(left), right(right) {}

 Hnode * readTree(string &text)
{
 if (text[0]=='L')
  return new Hnode(text[1])
 else {
  string s = text.substr(1,text.size());
  return new Hnode(readTree(s), readTree(s));
  }
}
```

To briefly explain I have written my encode so I receive a a string that tells me what my huffman tree looked like. For example I am using the example ILaILbILrILcLd. Which means whenever there is an I there is a empty socket sorta, and L means a new leaf so when you see ILcLd you can see that there are two leafs(c and d) attacked to an empty one.

I am getting errors saying that there are no matching functions to Hnode::Hnode(char&), which boggles my mind a bit, since I don't make any chars in this function.

Comment: but you don`t have such constructor..., return new Hnode(string(&text[1], 1))...

Answer (score 0):

You try to construct a `Hnode` from a `char`, but your constructor only allows `std::string`. `char` is not convertible to `std::string`. See [the constructor documentation of basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Don't be tempted to use the `CharT*` constructor of `basic_string` with something like `&text[1]`. This will do something you absolutely don't want.

So what can you do? Use the constructor taking a `size`

```
std::string(1, text[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

text[1] is a char.  So new HNode(text[1]) is trying to call the constructor Hnode::Hnode( char ).  Which you haven't provided.